# c# - Get a string line from a text file and show the text in a label

Tags: c#

I'm studying C# and creating this program to learn a bit more.
My program catchs the information that you have input and save it into a text file. In this part, is alright, but I'm having issues on load the file and show the information inside it.
Example, in the program I have the text boxes for user input his family information:
*Dad text box:*
*Mom text box:*
*Brother text box:*
The text box input is something like:
*Dad text box: MyDad*
*Mom text box: MyMom*
*Brother text box: MyBrother*
When the creation process of file starts, I have in the file the output that I want:
*MyDad

MyMom

MyBrother*
Okay, now I need to load these informations from the file and write it in another labels, like:
*Your Dad is: according to example, I want "MyDad" shown here

Your Mother is: according to example, I want "MyMother" shown here

Your Brother is: according to example, I want "MyBrother" shown here*

In the click event of the button to show the informations of the file I have this to check if the file was created and, if was, read it:

```
string path = @"C:\Users\Hypister\Desktop\Family.txt";
if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
                {
                    //Here I need the function to get the lines and show it in respective labels.
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The file doesn't exists. Data cannot be loaded.");
            }
```

But I cannot get the line for Dad, Mother and Brother from the file to show.
I hope someone can answer this and help me to gain more knowledge.
Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Start your search here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: concept is search for your keyword, split it take the 2nd part of your selected result and display it

Comment: I've searched but encountered nothing to the purpose I want. I need to write the lines in program from the file.

Comment: If the sequence is always the same like you have added/appended in the file, and number of fields are known, then you simply have to write and read from the file. Write separate methods for writing and reading from the file.

Comment: I suggest your file should have an identifier for each data. For example, Father:Juan;Mother:Juana;Brother:Jose; You can use string.Split() function. With this you can identify which data is appropriate for you label specially if you have fixed number of fields.

Comment: With the answer below, I managed to do this with the line count.
Your suggestion also would be nice, and now I want to learn more about this. I've heard about the string.Split() and I'll keep this in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I coded an example for you a good C# file reference is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx for future reference.

there 3 textboxes 3 labels and a button all default names

here is the source code hope it helps :)

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> family = new List<string>();
        family.Add(textBox1.Text);
        family.Add(textBox2.Text);
        family.Add(textBox3.Text);

        family.ToArray();

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\OEM\Desktop\stackoverflow\test.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string line in family)
            {                   
                    file.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }

        string[] familyout = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\OEM\Desktop\stackoverflow\test.txt");

        /*  this works just fine unless you have alot of labels, the code not commented out below this works better
        label1.Text = familyout[0];
        label2.Text = familyout[1];
        label3.Text = familyout[2];
        */

        int i = 0;

        foreach (Control lbl in this.Controls)
        {
            if (lbl is Label)
            {
                lbl.Text = familyout[i];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would add another `if` to check if i >= familyout.length

Comment: haha' thank you my friend! This was exactily what I wanted: count the lines and modify the label. Worked perfectily! A great hug to you and in all who tried to help!